# Is there anyway we can detect whether a playback is in avsync or not using pts of audio and video buffers?

Tags: gstreamer, media-player, audio-video-sync

I am having a media player which is basically a gstreamer(playbin) based application media playback.
From gstreamer logs how can i identify using pts values of audio and video buffers whether the playback has avsync issue or not ?
And if pts is not used is there any other method for detecting avsync.